# open a new window in electron without refreshing angular service data

Tags: angular, service, electron

I want to open a new window in my electron + angular app. I have a service `auth.service.ts` that handle my authentication to the app. I have a function that triggers the opening of a new electron window to show some other part of the app. The issue I am facing is that when the new window is opened it is redirecting me back to the login page. How can I fix this issue?

This is my `main.js` file

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const url = 'http://localhost:4200'

let win, printWin

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1440,
        height: 720,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        resizable: false,
        maximizable: false,
        icon: `file://${__dirname}/src/favicon.ico`,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: `${__dirname}/preload.js`,
            print: true
        }
    })

    win.loadURL(url)

    win.on('closed', function () {
        win = null
    })

}

function openPrintWindow(arg) {
    printWin = new BrowserWindow({ parent: win, modal: true, show: false })

    printWin.loadURL(`${url}/#/${arg}`)
    printWin.once('ready-to-show', () => printWin.show())
}

function readyToPrint() {
    win.webContents.print({
        printBackground: true,
        silent: true
    }, function () {
        printWin = null
    })
}

ipcMain.on('print', (event, arg) => openPrintWindow(arg))
ipcMain.on('readyToPrint', (event, arg) => readyToPrint(arg))
app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

Please note here that I am using the localhost for displaying the app due to certain limitations of Laravel Sanctum. And I am using the hash strategy here.

Comment: U need to use plugin like vuex-electron (this for vue) it can persist state between other windows

Comment: try this > https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/issues/365#issuecomment-513761160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to understand about electron is the fact that each window behaves similar to browser tab in many aspects. In your case in new window angular will be initialized from scratch meaning new instance of your auth service which knows nothing about another window where user has logged in already.

There are multiple ways to pass login information to newly open window from localStorage to IPC communication.

As an option you can keep access token in local storage and read it from there at the angular startup. In this case login information will be shared across all windows in your app.

Comment: I like the idea of using IPC communication than localStorage, can you show me how exactly should I do it? I can pass the user details as an argument to the function call, then what? How can I make Angular register those into my services before hitting the guards